# Setting (setq system-time-locale "C") in daemon ineffective

Tags: time-date, daemon

I try to set the time locale to "C" in my config via `(setq system-time-locale "C")`. However, when using the `emacs --daemon`, it is not set properly and I end up with non-english date formats and weekday abbreviations when the system locale is different.

How can I set the time locale when using the daemon?

Comment: I can reproduce this, setting `system-time-locale` in the init file.  The variable holds that value I assigned, but `(format-time-string "%c")` behaves as if it were still `nil`.  Curious.

Comment: In fact the custom setting is respected when the daemon starts, but not for client frames.  So it's behaving somewhat like a terminal-local variable -- except it's not documented as such, and on inspection the variable indicates the custom value in the new frames.

Comment: It looks to me as if the lisp variable isn't used directly.  There are internal C functions which read the lisp variable and use that to set the *real* value, so my guess is that internally the real value actually is terminal-local in effect, and that `synchronize_system_time_locale` or similar is not being called to set that for new client frames.  It sounds like a bug to me.  `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and the deep dive into what might be wrong. I'll file a bug report and report back, once I hear anything.

Comment: Any update? I use org-journal in two locales and its causing havoc not having a common emacs date format.

Comment: @RichieHH Indeed, the daemon was started from bash. Set the bash locale to the one you need. In fact, I had mismatching zsh and bash locales which caused confusion for me. Here is the entire ticket: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=42921